# Wordpress: No change after I use modifying CSS added through theme's “add CSS” page

Tags: css, wordpress, wordpress-theming, customization

I am using the Literatum theme and am running WP on my own server. I am not using a child theme. I've searched this forum and can't find any answers here.

You can see my site at http://greggwilliams.co. I am trying to modify the "Over NNNN followers..." in the upper left corner.

In Literatum, you modify the CSS in a sanctioned manner through  --> Theme Options --> Custom Styles. My site has no option for changing CSS in any other way--there is no such option under the standard WP Appearance submenu.

I looked at the HTML for my site's front page and used the Firefox code inspector to get the correct CSS selectors.

The CSS modification I want to make is:

```
div.logo .logo-legend p {width:       500px;
                         font-family: 'PT Sans', sans-serif;}
```

My intent is to get the desired text all on one line by increasing the width of the field for the desired text.

(NOTE: This code worked for the previous version of the theme. Grrrr...)

I'm stumped. Anybody have any ideas? Thanks!

Comment: You have FTP/SSH access? Maybe it's a problem based on permitions, so your theme can't change the styles (that are all inline).

By the way, you can use `white-space: nowrap` instead increasing width.

Comment: Which version are you using ? 1.4.3 ?

Comment: Thanks for the comments so far; I'll try them. "white-space: nowrap" didn't help.

My version of WordPress is 4.6.1. Yes, the version number for the Literatum theme is 1.4.3.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Though your Theme provided Custom CSS is not working,you can install and activate this plugin: https://wordpress.org/plugins/simple-custom-css/

After activate you will see a new option here: Dashboard->Appearance -> Custom CSS

```
div.logo .logo-legend {
    width: 100%;
}
```

Font family have already implemented as you wanted. So just use this code and hope will get solution.

Comment: Akramul, dunno what's wrong with the theme, but adding the CSS using the Simple Custom CSS plugin worked the first time. Many thanks!

Comment: Dear Gregg,feeling good to hear your issue has solved.I can guess the problem of your theme.May be the file for custom css of your theme encripted in wrong way.Anyway if you need any help just send me a message.Thanks